# Writing data to Excel using Python For Loops

Tags: python, database, excel

I am currently converting PDFS to text in a giant folder and then outputting certain key words to an Excel file. Everything is working correctly except that even though I have multiple PDFS in my folder, they are over writing each other on column A1.

How do I iterate it so the next dictionary goes to the subsequent row?

```
custData = {}

def data_grabbing(pdf):
    row = 0
    col = 0
    string = convert_pdf_to_txt(pdf)
    lines = list(filter(bool,string.split('\n')))
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if 'Lead:' in lines[i]:
            custData['Name'] = lines[i+2]
        elif 'Date:Date:Date:Date:' in lines[i]:
            custData['Fund Manager'] = lines[i+2]
        elif 'Priority:' in lines[i]:
            custData['Industry'] = lines[i+2]
            custData['Date'] = lines[i+1]
            custData['Deal Size']= lines [i+3]
        elif 'DEAL QUALIFYING MEMORANDUM' in lines[i]:
            custData['Owner'] = lines[i+2]
        elif 'Fund Manager' in lines[i]:
            custData['Investment Type'] = lines [i+2]
    print custData
    for item, descrip in custData.iteritems():
        worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
        worksheet.write(row+1, col, descrip)
        col += 1
    row +=2


for myFile in os.listdir(directory):
    if myFile.endswith(".pdf"):
        data_grabbing(os.path.join(directory, myFile))
workbook.close()
```

Comment: move the `row +=2` to inside your `for item...` loop

Comment: I tried that but now my output on my excel file looks like a zig zag ladder

Comment: Take the col += 1 out if you want the results to stay in column A

Comment: Quick and dirty:  put `row = 0` outside your function in global scope.  Inside your fucntion replace `row = 0` with `global row`.   Not really the best way to handle persistent state, but you can get away with it.

Comment: @Gerrat: OP is writing columnwise for an individual PDF.  I believe you missed that with your advice to move `row += 2` inside the loop.  The OP's real issue is that the next call to `data_grabbing` doesn't start two rows down (and then two more rows down on another call and so on).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski:  Correct.  I glossed over it too quickly.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I moved row = 0 outside of the function and replaced it with "global row = 0". However I am getting a Syntax Error for "Global Row = 0"

Comment: Not `global row = 0`.  Simply `global row` on a line, by itself.  It's a directive that when you assign to the name `row` inside your function you want to affect the global scope.

Comment: Do you understand that my suggestion was for the following changes?  Outside of your function add a line `row = 0`.  Inside your function delete the line `row = 0`.  Inside your function add a line `global row` (preferably put it where `row = 0` used to be).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Yes that did the trick. Thank you all very much that was very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your options are:

1. make `row` a global, and instantiate outside function (@StevenRumbalski's suggestion)
2. Make `datag_grabbing` a method of a class, and make row an instance variable.
3. Pass the current row into your function.

I'll show option #3 (but #2 might be preferrable):

```
custData = {}

def data_grabbing(pdf, row):
    col = 0
    string = convert_pdf_to_txt(pdf)
    lines = list(filter(bool,string.split('\n')))
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if 'Lead:' in lines[i]:
            custData['Name'] = lines[i+2]
        elif 'Date:Date:Date:Date:' in lines[i]:
            custData['Fund Manager'] = lines[i+2]
        elif 'Priority:' in lines[i]:
            custData['Industry'] = lines[i+2]
            custData['Date'] = lines[i+1]
            custData['Deal Size']= lines [i+3]
        elif 'DEAL QUALIFYING MEMORANDUM' in lines[i]:
            custData['Owner'] = lines[i+2]
        elif 'Fund Manager' in lines[i]:
            custData['Investment Type'] = lines [i+2]
    print custData
    for item, descrip in custData.iteritems():
        worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
        worksheet.write(row+1, col, descrip)
        col += 1


cur_row = 0
for myFile in os.listdir(directory):
    if myFile.endswith(".pdf"):
        data_grabbing(os.path.join(directory, myFile), cur_row)
        cur_row +=-2
workbook.close()
```